# Weblogic classloading issue with javassist

Tags: java, weblogic, javassist

I am deploying a java web application on weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 in a form of a war file.
Here is a fragment of my weblogic.xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
   ...
   <package-name>javassist</package-name>
   ...
</prefer-application-packages>
```

javassist library is present in WEB-INF/lib -> javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar

However, during the application deployment the following exception is caught:

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
```

P.S. Deployment on my local system goes fine - i only face the described issue on a remote host where i deploy the application. Both application servers have the same 12.1.3.0.0 version.

Any ideas of what causes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

I think that the one you are using is for APP-INF/lib

Comment: I tried that as well, but still no luck since some exclusions like javax.persistance doesn't get covered by that approach.
Still, that same deployment runs fine on one stand and fails to start on another one. That makes me think of some environment issue like application server configuration.

Comment: I think you should leave the prefer-application-packages logic in place in conjunction with the prefer-web-inf-classes logic an then try that. Failing that I would go to the Class Loader Analysis tool and try to figure out if the .jar is getting picked up at all.